# Turn off Radiometric Enhancement ("DRA") when downloading Worldview-2 imagery

Tags: worldview-2

I am trying to calculate the TOA reflectance for worldview-2 images, but every time I download the WV-2 8 band imagery from DigitalGlobe, the metadata states that the image has been radiometrically enhanced and the absolute calibration factor is -9999, which is obviously not correct. Does anyone know how to set radiometricEnhancement to "off"? I can not figure out how to do this.

```
radiometricLevel = "Corrected";
radiometricEnhancement = "DRA";
bitsPerPixel = 8;
compressionType = "None";
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_C
    ...
    absCalFactor = -9.990000e+02;
```

Answer (score 0):

When downloading digital globe imagery, you can either select "Basic All Bands" or "Ortho All Bands". The basic selection is does not have dynamic range adjustment (DRA) applied, and so it does include the absolute calibration factor. The downside is that it is not orthorectified, and so another step is added.

If you download the "Ortho All Bands", the image has been orthorectified, but unfortunately also DRA has been applied, thus making it unsuitable for time change comparisons etc. At least, this is my (limited) understanding. Please correct if this is false.